# CXF HTTP Conduit Java Configuration

Tags: java, cxf

I am trying to understand how to configure a http cxf conduit using java annotations rather than using spring.xml.

Here is the xml that I want convert to a java bean.

```
<http-conf:conduit name="*.http-conduit">
        <http-conf:client ConnectionTimeout="${http.connection.timeout:300000}"
                          ReceiveTimeout="${http.read.timeout:300000}"/>
        <http-conf:tlsClientParameters
                disableCNCheck="${transport.tslClientParameters.disableCNCheck}">
            <sec:trustManagers>
                <sec:keyStore type="${transport.tslClientParameters.storeType}"
                              resource="${transport.tslClientParameters.trustStore}"
                              password="${transport.tslClientParameters.trustStorePassword}"/>
            </sec:trustManagers>
            <sec:cipherSuitesFilter>
                <sec:include>.*_EXPORT_.*</sec:include>
                <sec:include>.*_EXPORT1024_.*</sec:include>
                <sec:include>.*_WITH_DES_.*</sec:include>
                <sec:include>.*_WITH_AES_.*</sec:include>
                <sec:include>.*_WITH_NULL_.*</sec:include>
                <sec:exclude>.*_DH_anon_.*</sec:exclude>
            </sec:cipherSuitesFilter>
        </http-conf:tlsClientParameters>
    </http-conf:conduit>
```

So far I have tried looking at the documentation in [Apache CXF Documentation](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html#ClientHTTPTransport(includingSSLsupport)-HowtoconfiguretheHTTPConduitfortheSOAPClient?) but still does not give much of a clue.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old post but as i was stuck with the same probleme this is what i did:

```
public <T> T createSoapClient(Class<T> serviceClass, URL endpoint, String namespace)
{
    ClientProxyFactoryBean factory = new ClientProxyFactoryBean();
    Bus bus = new ExtensionManagerBus(null, null, Bus.class.getClassLoader());
    factory.setBus(bus);
    factory.setServiceClass(serviceClass);
    factory.setServiceName(new QName(namespace, serviceClass.getSimpleName()));
    factory.setAddress(endpoint.toString());
    factory.getServiceFactory().getServiceConfigurations().add(0, new XFireCompatabilityConfiguration());
    factory.setDataBinding(new AegisDatabinding());
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    T soapClient = (T) factory.create();
    Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(soapClient);
    client.getRequestContext().put(Message.MAINTAIN_SESSION, true);
    HTTPClientPolicy policy = new HTTPClientPolicy();
    policy.setReceiveTimeout(600000);
    policy.setAllowChunking(false);
    HTTPConduit conduit = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();
    conduit.setClient(policy);
    return soapClient;
}
```

Thanks to: https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit